# Запуск сервиса при нажатии кнопки на фрагменте

Tags: java, android

Добрый день. Уже второй день не могу понять в чем проблема... Перепробовал уже все варианты с интернета, в том числе и англоязычного.
Есть фрагмент(MonitoringFragment ), на нем кнопка (startService), обработчик следующий:

```
startService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("myE", "Start click");
                try
                {
                    Context ctx = (Context)MonitoringFragment.this.getActivity();
                    ctx.startService(new Intent(getContext(), CheckService.class));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                    Log.d("myE", e.toString());    
                Log.d("myE", "End click");
            }
}
```

Сам сервис:

```
public class CheckService extends Service
{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.d("myE", "onStartCommand");
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

В манифесте прописал так (MonitoringFragment - это сам фрагмент):

```
<service android:name=".MonitoringFragment$CheckService" />
```

При запуске в лог выводится следующее:
D/myE: Start click
D/myE: End click

В чем моя ошибка? Спасибо!

Comment: Stacktrace в студию пожалуйста

Comment: Проблему решил, спасибо)